# как сделать автопостинг твитов из твиттера через телеграм бота в телеграм канал или группу на python? можно даже что бы это был парсер

Tags: python, парсер

как сделать автопостинг твитов из твиттера через телеграм бота в телеграм канал или группу на python? можно даже что бы это был парсер

я прошу код или ссылку где я могу найти что то подобное

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто. С помощью библиотеки [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) делаете запрос к странице твитера. Библиотекой [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) извлекаете данные из html. И наконец отсылаете сообщение в телеграм [Telebot](https://pypi.org/project/telebot/).

Comment: такого в интернете достаточно. и оно толлько для сайтов, а мне нужна подробная инструкция или код про твиттер.

Comment: Возможно вы перепутали сайт, тут вам не будут с нуля писать код, вы прежде чем задать вопрос, попытались что-то написать сами? Я вам достаточно подробно расписал алгоритм работы бота. Если вы сами не хотите учиться, тут вам не помогут